# SDK Support for Document Service

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I would like to connect the Document Service from Java (Spring Boot application deployed in SAP BTP Cloud Foundry environment with multitenancy) and I am wondering about the intended way to connect the document service in a multitenant szenario.

Does SAP cloud sdk helps with connectivity?

Comment: Are you referring to this service: https://api.sap.com/api/DocumentService/resource ?

Comment: That's an interesting link, thank you. However it seems to be about a Document Service related to projects.
I am delevoping a service myself and want to provide some document management functionality using https://help.sap.com/viewer/f6e70dd4bffa4b65965b43feed4c9429/Cloud/en-US

What I did so far is using the apache chemistry java client (chemistry-opencmis-client-impl) to connect to the document service hosted in my provider subaccount using oauth client credentials. And then maybe creating one repository per tenant.

But I am not sure if this is the intendet way?!

Comment: The documentation https://help.sap.com/viewer/b0cc1109d03c4dc299c215871eed8c42/Cloud/en-US/87b51b9fa8684995aa050277b26b7dcd.html does not mention how to implement multitenancy.

Comment: If you find a service endpoint which exposes a WDSL specification, you can try putting that into the code generator of Axis2. The SAP Cloud SDK provides an integration with Axis2 to invoke SOAP services. Check this blog post: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/09/13/deep-dive-17-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-convenient-consumption-of-sap-s4hana-soap-apis/

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about consuming the service on the SAP Business Technology platform - then yes. Check the [multi-tenancy docs](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/multi-tenancy/multi-tenancy-thread-context).

The [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/overview/overview-cloud-sdk) is a framework for consuming services and usually not the best choice for publishing them. You can use it as a proxy or data adapter, of course, if that's what you need.

For service publishing with multi-tenancy, I'd recommend looking into the direction of the [Cloud Application Programming model (CAP)](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/)

Are you building [OData](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generate-typed-odata-v2-and-v4-client-for-java), [OpenAPI](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/rest/generate-rest-client) or generic REST enabled service? The SAP Cloud SDK can help to consume your service with multi-tenancy out of the box using our OData or OpenAPI code generators and type-safe clients. You can also use the SDK for testing. Please, check the details in our [docs](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/getting-started).

I'd also recommend checking if the service you're building already exists or you can adapt some other service with help of the SDK.